# Why are the Emptys moving forward faster?

Tags: animation, cloth-simulation, empty

[image]**In this animation, the Emptys move faster than the rest for an inexplicable reason. Sorry, I can’t upload a video. If anyone has an idea how to fix this, I’d be very happy to. **

Comment: Hello, please share the file, only keep the useful items: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/c/8/c82d032bc8885427360ab5a4b4363c90.blend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your empty *TuchHook.004* is parented to *Empty* but it is also parented to the bone called *Spine2* with a *Child Of* constraint. So it is double parented, thus this x2 movement. You need to choose either the parent or the constraint.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: your skirt is not correctly weighted, you need to select all its vertices in Edit mode and in the Obect Data panel > Vertex Group, choose the vertex group this object is supposed to be part of and click on Assign.